# Fullstack Kanban Application (React, Django) How to manage column state?

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, react-fullstack

I am a web dev noob so I apologize for my confusion in advance.

Background: I am attempting to create a full-stack kanban board application (think trello). I have a database that I have written using Django that exposes an API. I am attempting to use the information exposed via the API to create the kanban board. For example, my database has a table of columns:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Should",
    "dashboard": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-04-08T16:43:42.755280Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08T16:43:42.755316Z"
}
```

There also exists a table of cards:

```
{
    "id": 14,
    "title": "This goes in must",
    "description": "You must do this...",
    "label": "",
    "comment": "",
    "created_at": "2021-04-19T17:44:31.332763Z",
    "column": 1,
    "position": 0
}
```

Problem: I am confused about how to work with this API on the front end. If I were using static data, each of my columns would have a list of cards and I would simply use the list of cards attached to the respective column to manage the state of the columns (there are many examples of this online). However, in my case, my columns have no reference to the cards that are contained within. How do I work with this?

Basically, in App I fetch both the columns and cards from my database using the fetch() method. This gives me an array of card objects called cards and an array of column objects called lists. Then in Apps return I simply create the columns using the list array.

```
lists.map((list, index) =>
<List title={ list.title } cards={cards} listID={list.id} key={list.id} index={index}/>
```

Then, in my list component I iterate over the cards and create the corresponding component.

```
cards.map( (card, index) => {
//if(card.column === listID)
return (<CardItem title={card.title} description={card.description}
id = {card.id} index={index} key={card.id}/>);
}
```

Here is the start of the problem, the cards array is ALL of the cards that exist in the database. So, when I go to create these columns they each get every single card regardless of whether that card belongs to them. To solve this, I have attempted to add a condition in my list component to only render cards where column === list.id. While this does render the correct cards in the correct columns, I still have problems when I attempt to rearrange the cards because I don't know how to manage the state of the columns. Say someone drags a card to a different column, how do I reflect that when I only have an array of cards? I mean, I have an array of columns, but it is effectively useless. It looks like this and I can't use it to control the state of the column.

```
0: Object { id: 1, title: "Must", created_at: "2021-04-08T00:41:45.338443Z", … }

1: Object { id: 3, title: "Should", dashboard: 1, … }
```

I'm very confused about how to work with the columns properly. Do I need to redesign the way they are stored on the database? How do I control their state when the array of column objects pulled from the database is effectively useless? Should I partition the array of cards based on their column id and use that to somehow control the state of the columns?

Any help/suggestions/resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, and have a good day.

Comment: You need to seperate each card with columns like example : col 1(in progress) | - col 2(bug checking) | - col3(done) |    according to initial state of your card am i right ?

Comment: I considered doing that. Like partitioning the card array based on the column? Is that what you are suggesting?